# Upgrading vb.net .netframework app to .net 6 missing application.xaml

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, .net-6.0

I'm trying to upgrade an existing Vb.net app from Netframework 4.8 to .Net 6 in VS 2022 and having all sorts of problems. Currently my most immediate issue is that I can't open the project properties page in VS. I get an error: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: The file ...\Application.xaml is not part of any project in the solution so it cannot be opened.  Add the file to a project and try again.

The file does not exist anywhere, nor are there any similar .xaml files as part of the project. I tried creating a new project, to see what that file is supposed to contain, but it also has no such file, and no error complaining about its absence. I've searched for some reference to application.xaml in every file I could open with notepad, without success.
Can anyone tell me, either how to create the file, and what's in it, or how to get rid of any reference that is preventing the project properties page from opening?

On a perhaps related note, or maybe not, the other big problem I have is an error claiming one of my projects targets framework 4.8, and it cannot reference a .net 6 project. But I've changed the framework in the vbproj file, and can't find any specific references to framework 4.8 anywhere. Any idea where it could be hiding?

I also get the error that windows.winmd can not be referenced in .net6, but I don't know what Windows metadata could be in my program, and double clicking on the error only takes me to the line that tells the program to check for winmd errors.

Comment: Except, I guess I failed to mention that I'm using Winforms, not WPF. Can I assume the two are interchangeable at least in this regard? I've created a WPF project, found the application.xaml, and tweaked it, and that particular error message went away, and I can get into project properties now.  Is there anything else that's supposed to be in that file, such as the app.config settings or something? And I still have that incomprehensible error that windowsmd can not be referenced. Should I open a new separate question for that and mark this one answered?

Comment: @JiachenLi-MSFT , I'm still getting an `App.xaml`  file and no "Application.xaml" in a new ".NET (6.0) WPF Application" project in VS2022 here, does that sound like a damaged VS setup?

Comment: @VBYooper Yes, it is recommended that open a new separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Application.xaml is the declarative portion of your code (usually generated by Visual Studio) extending System.Windows.Application.
If you create a new WPF project with .net 6, there should be an Application.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as this is a bug in the migration app **for .FORMS** projects.
I had to change the (new added) entry **UseWPF** from true to **false** in .vbproj.

Found the hint here:
[Application.xaml is not part of any projects in the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964390/application-xaml-is-not-part-of-any-projects-in-the-solution)