# Application.xaml is not part of any projects in the solution

Tags: visual-studio

I was just working and tried to add a resource to my project. Upon loading I get the error below. I ran an update to my visual studio earlier today VS Pro 2022 64x (17.3.5) so I don't know if that's what caused this? I went into my backups for over a month and I never even see this file having ever existed? I am a bit confused has anybody run into this or know how to fix? I did run a clean and rebuild but it did not help. Thanks!

```
=====================
10/5/2022 11:42:01 AM
Recoverable
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: The file P:\Projects\MyPortal\MyPortal\Application.xaml is not part of any project in the solution so it cannot be opened.  Add the file to a project and try again. ---> System.ArgumentException: The file P:\Projects\MyPortal\MyPortal\Application.xaml is not part of any project in the solution so it cannot be opened.  Add the file to a project and try again.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DocData..ctor(IServiceProvider provider, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WPF.ApplicationXamlFileAccessor.<<TryGetApplicationXamlFileAsync>g__GetDocDataAsync|11_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WPF.ApplicationXamlFileAccessor.<TryGetApplicationXamlFileAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WPF.ApplicationXamlFileAccessor.<GetStartupUriAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.WPFValueProvider.<GetPropertyValueAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.InterceptedProjectProperties.<GetUnevaluatedPropertyValueAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageProperty.<GetUnevaluatedValueFromDataSourceAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.UIPropertyValueDataProducer.<CreateUIPropertyValueValueAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.UIPropertyValueDataProducer.<CreateUIPropertyValueValueAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.UIPropertyValueDataProducer.<CreateUIPropertyValueValuesAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.QueryDataFromProviderStateProducerBase`1.<SendRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<RunQueryOnceAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Start>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<InitializeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<CreateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertiesEditor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.AsyncLoadContent.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Initialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()
===================
```

Comment: Upon trying to load my backups they all also now fail with the same error. I am pretty sure this bug was caused by upgrading my Visual Studio earlier today.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently in the newer versions of  Visual Studio 2022 there is a flag that is set to use WPF which causes the Application.xaml to not be found in a WinForms project.

To resolve this I opened up my .vbproj file and changed UseWPF from true to false then I was able to open my project properties again.
​

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Seems to be a (bad!) bug in the MS migration app.